# An application of Rouché's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, rouches-theorem

i need help to proof the next:

Let $f$ be analytic at $D$ minus a finite numbers of interior points where $f$ has poles. Show that if $0<|f(z)|<1$ over $\partial D$, then the number of poles of $f$ in $D$ is equal to the number of roots of the equation $f(z)=1$ in $D$.

I have tried to prove it using Rouché’s theorem, but i cannot conclude anything , I would appreciate your help.

Comment: write $1-f=g/h$ with $g,h$ analytic in the (closed) unit disc (in a minimal way so $g,h$ do not share zeroes) and then $0< |1-g/h| <1$ on the boundary so $g,h$ have the same number of zeroes (counted with multiplicity) in the unit disc; the zeroes of $g$ are the solutions of $1-f=0$ and the zeroes of $h$ are the poles of $f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Use the argument principle for $g(z)=1-f(z)$. What is the image of $\partial D$ under $g$?